# Parallel iteration through multiple lists with indexing on the iterated item

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I'm trying to execute a formula on multiple items in parallel which are taken from different lists.

1. First thing my lists are the following:

```
    l1= [1,2,3]
    l2= [4,5,6]
    l3= [7,8,9]
```

2. Next i need to create new set of lists from my main lists in order to compare each pair of elements inside the list:

```
    newl1 = list(zip(l1, l1[1:])) #outputs [(1,2), (2,3)]
    newl2 = list(zip(l2, l2[1:])) #outputs [(4,5), (5,6)]
    newl3 = list(zip(l3, l3[1:])) #outputs [(7,8), (8,9)]
```

3. Now i want to iterate through all the new set of lists in parallel, with the ability to compare the tuple lists elements:

```
    for pair_of_newl1, pair_of_newl2, pair_of_newl3 in newl1, newl2, newl3:
        if pair_of_newl1[0] > pair_of_newl1[1]:
            x = pair_of_newl1[0] + pair_of_newl2[1] + pair_of_newl3[1]
            print (x)
        elif pair_of_newl1[0] < pair_of_newl1[1]:
            x = pair_of_newl1[0] - pair_of_newl2[1] - pair_of_newl3[1]
            print (x)
```

Expecting that in first iteration:

```
    pair_of_newl1 = (1,2)
    pair_of_newl2 = (4,5)
    pair_of_newl3 = (7,8)
```

Thus being able to compare the items inside them by indexing.

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I was confused, and deleted the last list leaving only two lists to work with:

```
l1= [1,2,3]
l2= [4,5,6]

newl1 = list(zip(l1, l1[1:])) #outputs [(1,2), (2,3)]
newl2 = list(zip(l2, l2[1:])) #outputs [(4,5), (5,6)]

for pair_of_newl1, pair_of_newl2 in newl1, newl2:
    if pair_of_newl1[0] > pair_of_newl1[1]:
        x = pair_of_newl1[0] + pair_of_newl2[1]
        print (x)
    elif pair_of_newl1[0] < pair_of_newl1[1]:
        x = pair_of_newl1[0] - pair_of_newl2[1]
        print (x)
    print (pair_of_newl1, pair_of_newl2) #just to see how the loop works
```

And i'm getting:

```
-1
(1, 2) (2, 3)
-1
(4, 5) (5, 6)
```

So by my understanding pair_of_newl2 is taken as the second item of newl1, but why not newl2 ?

Help please.

Comment: Considering that in this situation only the second condition is met, i would expect x = 1 - 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add `zip` to iterate them:

```
for pair_of_newl1, pair_of_newl2 in zip(newl1, newl2):
```

And the result:

```
-4
(1, 2) (4, 5)
-4
(2, 3) (5, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because the line: `for pair_of_newl1, pair_of_newl2, pair_of_newl3 in newl1, newl2, newl3` tries to iterate through the three lists, extracting three elements from each. But the newl-lists only have two elements, each. That won't work.

If you want to loop through parallel lists, you may either zip them (which would make the indexing a little more complicated in your case) or you may use an index iterator:

```
     for i in range(len(newl1)): # For index 0 and 1, each of the list has
        if newl1[i][0] > newl1[i][1]:
            x = newl1[i][0] + newl2[i][1] + newl2[i][1]
            print(x)
        elif newl1[i][0] > newl1[i][1]:
            x = newl1[i][0] - newl2[i][1] - newl2[i][1]
            print (x)
```

This will loop through the two tuples of the three lists and either add the second element of the second and third list to the first element of the first or subtract them.

Is this what you wanted to do?